# Dapr Sidecar Not Created when Binding to HTTPS - Error Message "Dapr has been disabled for unbound service xx"

Tags: .net, dapr, tye

I am working on a project that involves multiple .NET projects. To run these projects simultaneously, I am using 'tye.' For communication with other services and state management, I am utilizing 'dapr.' There is a specific service for which I need to set the port manually, and it should be run in HTTPS protocol. However, when I set the protocol to HTTPS, the dapr sidecar is not functioning. Surprisingly, it works fine when I set it to HTTP.

I want this particular service to run on HTTPS, and I also want the dapr sidecar to function properly. Can someone help me achieve this?

when I set the protocol to https we can't see the dapr sidecar
[image]

as you can see when I set the protocol to http we can see the dapr sidecar
[image]

terminal output when I set the protocol to HTTPS IN tye yaml file

```
PS C:\Users\source\repos\USerManangementAPP> tye run -v debug
Loading Application Details...
Restoring and evaluating projects
Resolved metadata for service usermanangement at C:\Users\source\repos\USerManangementAPP\USerManangementAPP\obj\Debug\net6.0\MicrosoftTye.ProjectMetadata.txt
Restore and project evaluation took: 1719.5596ms
Found application version: 1.0.0
RunCommand=C:\Users\source\repos\USerManangementAPP\USerManangementAPP\bin\Debug\net6.0\USerManangementAPP.exe
RunArguments=
TargetPath=C:\Users\source\repos\USerManangementAPP\USerManangementAPP\bin\Debug\net6.0\USerManangementAPP.dll
PublishDir=bin\Debug\net6.0\publish\
AssemblyName=USerManangementAPP
IntermediateOutputPath=obj\Debug\net6.0\
Found target framework: net6.0
Parsed target framework name: net
Parsed target framework version: 6.0
Found shared frameworks: Microsoft.NETCore.App, Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
IsAspNet=True
Evaluation Took: 2.2898ms
Dapr has been disabled for unbound service usermanangement.
Launching Tye Host...

[12:26:24 INF] Default dashboard port 8000 has been reserved by the application or is in use, choosing random port.
[12:26:24 INF] Executing application from C:\Users\source\repos\USerManangementAPP\tye.yaml
[12:26:24 INF] Dashboard running on http://127.0.0.1:53376
[12:26:24 INF] Build Watcher: Watching for builds...
[12:26:24 INF] Building projects
[12:26:26 INF] Application usermanangementapp started successfully with Pid: 28376
[12:26:26 INF] Launching service usermanangement_f873c37e-b: C:\Users\source\repos\USerManangementAPP\USerManangementAPP\bin\Debug\net6.0\USerManangementAPP.exe 
[12:26:26 INF] usermanangement_f873c37e-b running on process id 18884 bound to https://localhost:5001
[12:26:26 INF] Replica usermanangement_f873c37e-b is moving to a ready state
[12:26:26 INF] Selected process 18884.
[12:26:26 INF] Listening for event pipe events for usermanangement_f873c37e-b on process id 18884
```